# htaccess remove index.php from url/folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I have a problem and couldn't find a working solution on the internet. So hopefully you can help me.

I need to make my website as SEO friendly as possible. Therefore I need to change the following

```
https://www.example.com/index.php
https://www.example.com/folder/index.php
https://www.example.com/folder/folder/index.php
```

To:

```
https://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/folder/
https://www.example.com/folder/folder/
```

I need some kinda canonical redirect so that my website is only accessible without the /index.php in order to eliminate duplicate content.

I would like to use .htaccess. Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create .htaccess in the main domain (www.example.com/) and put below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```